# synchronisation of threads, during calculation of time difference in boost multi threaded program in unix

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, posix

```
boost::mutex time_;
void checkForDays(string dir,string hdir,int i)
{
..................
..................
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(time_);
if(lock)
    {
     try
     {
        t = last_write_time( <file> ) ;
     }
     catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e)
     {
        out << currentDateTime() << " [ERROR]: " << e.what() << std::endl;//throw the exceptions if any
     }

     n = time( 0 ) ;
     diff = n - t;
    **diff = (diff / 86400);**
    } //scope of lock ends here

    **if(diff < <somedate>)**
    {
     .. do something ..
    }
    else{
    .. do something 
    }
}

int main()
{
........................
........................
    while(k<totalcount)
    {

     for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ , k++)
     {
     workerThreads[i]=boost::thread (boost::bind(checkForDays,str_temp_out,str_temp_hist,k));
     }
     for (int z=0 ; z<2 ; z++)
     {
     workerThreads[z].join();
      }
    }
}
```

The time difference calculated seems to be working perfectly fine, for smaller inputs. But for exponentially growing huge inputs, the time difference calculated doesn't seem to be right.

How do we maintain perfect thread synchronization for this part of critical section?? Should we static_cast<> the diff value from time_t to long int on a local stack space created for each thread?

Comment: You should format your code a bit for better readability.

Comment: sorry :( copy pasted from notepad, hence the bad formatting present in the code

Comment: Replace all tabs with spaces before copying.

Comment: Can you please show a runnable program with the inputs which cause your problem?

Comment: @SlardarZhang.. Hi, in my code I am looping over all the files in a directory, checking the last modified time of each file, and comparing it to the time diff(in number of days) from the current time. I am creating a new worker_thread for each of the directories to be scanned.
The program seems to work fine with 50 directories and 100 files in each of the directory.
But, as soon as I increase the number of directories to 1000, program seems to behave a little weirdly.